# How to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{2x+1}=1$ using $\delta-\epsilon$ definition?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

**How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2x+1}=1$ using $\delta-\epsilon$ definition?**

I have the following so far-

$|x-0|<\delta$ and $\left|\frac{1}{2x+1}-1\right|<\epsilon$

which boils to $\left|\frac{-2x}{2x+1}\right|<\epsilon$

I'm trying to figure out a way to factor out an $x$ but don't know how

Comment: @obscurans Thanks for you effort to edit posts into better shape. I'll just mention that you can use `\lim` to get nicer rendering and also proper spacing for the limit symbol. For example `$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$` $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ or `$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$` $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$.

Answer (score 3):

So you want
$|\dfrac{2x}{2x+1}|<\epsilon
$.

There are two ways  go here.

For the first,
note that you don't need 
the best bounds,
just one that will work.

Soppose
$|x| < \dfrac14$.
Then
$|2x| < \dfrac12$
so
$|1+2x| > 1-2\cdot \dfrac14
= \dfrac12$.
Therefore
$|\dfrac{2x}{2x+1}|
\lt |\dfrac{2x}{\frac12}|
=|4x|
$.
To make
$|4x| < \epsilon$,
you just need
$|x| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{4}$.

Therefore,
if $|x| < \min(\dfrac14, \dfrac{\epsilon}{4})$,
we have
$|\dfrac{2x}{2x+1}|<\epsilon
$.

If you want the *best* bounds,
$|\dfrac{2x}{2x+1}|<\epsilon
$
is the same as
$\dfrac1{\epsilon}
\lt |\dfrac{2x+1}{2x}|
= |1+\dfrac{1}{2x}|
$.

If $x > 0$,
$|1+\dfrac{1}{2x}|
=1+\dfrac{1}{2x}
$
so we want
$\dfrac1{\epsilon}
\lt 1+\dfrac{1}{2x}
$
or
$\dfrac1{\epsilon}-1
\lt \dfrac{1}{2x}
$
or,
assuming $\epsilon < 1$,
$2x
\lt \dfrac1{\dfrac1{\epsilon}-1}
= \dfrac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}
$
or
$x
\lt\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1-\epsilon)}
$.

If $x < 0$,
to make
$\dfrac1{\epsilon}
\lt |1+\dfrac{1}{2x}|
$
be easy to work with,
we need
$1+\dfrac{1}{2x} < 0$
or
$x > -\dfrac12$.

If this holds,
then
$|1+\dfrac{1}{2x}|
=-\dfrac{1}{2x}-1
$,
so we want
$-\dfrac{1}{2x}-1
\gt \dfrac1{\epsilon}
$
or
$-\dfrac{1}{2x}
\gt \dfrac1{\epsilon}+1
$
or
$-2x
\lt \dfrac1{\dfrac1{\epsilon}+1}
$
or
$-x
\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{2(1+\epsilon)}
$.

I always prefer to get
a simple bound 
which is not the best.

Answer (score 1):

For $\quad\delta<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2(1-\varepsilon)}\implies\quad\displaystyle\left|\dfrac{-2x}{2x+1}\right|<\dfrac{2\delta}{2\delta+1}=\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2\delta}}<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

$\mid\frac{-2x}{2x+1}\mid=\mid\frac{-2}{2+\frac1x}\mid\lt\mid\frac2{\frac 1x}\mid\lt\epsilon$.  So make $\mid x\mid\lt\frac{\epsilon}2$.  That is, $\delta =\frac {\epsilon}2$.